# PHP add new product function, create new subfolder to the product

Tags: php, mysql, e-commerce

I have an e-commerce website, and in the admin menu, I want to create a function so the authorized users can add new products to the site. I have the form page and the PHP script that uploads the data to the MYSQL Database, but thats it.

If I want to see the data of the product, I have created a single `product.php` file which gets the `id` using the `$_GET['id']` method, and a PHP script will show you all the information about the product with the selected id.

Now it would work perferctly for me, but since this is a webshop, the `SEO` ranking is a essential, but you can't get ranking to a single page (I mean it won't appear in the search engines if you search for a specific product which avalaible in my webshop). So I was wondering what would be the best way to add new products to the website and increase the `SEO` ranking.

My idea is to create dynamically a subfolder for all the added products, and put the connected files in that folder, so every products would have a unique folder, with a unique index.php page so they could get `SEO` ranking.

I need your opinions about this, because I have read a bunch of articles about this topic, but I haven't found an acceptable answer so far. So would my idea be acceptable, or do you guys know any better way to approach this situation?

Comment: Look into "PHP router", there's a ton out there and they're also easy to roll your own. The gist is that you instruct the server (Apache, Nginx, etc.) that instead of sending a 404 for missing file/directory, to instead send those requests to a specific PHP file to process. So that means `/product/65/my-cool-thing`, which would normally 404, will go to your router and you can parse the URL and look up the product.